# How to implement scroll to fixed effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you look at the website:

http://eyeheartworld.org/pages/the-cause

and scroll down, there's an implementation of a concept I found on codepen (when you scroll down, the navigation bar scrolls and is fixed)

```
    var header = $("#guide-template");
    $(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
       if (scroll >= window.innerHeight) {
          header.addClass("fixed");
        } else {
          header.removeClass("fixed");
        }
});
```

(http://codepen.io/simpleminded/pen/noaJj) and I just wanted a quick run through at the least of how the PICTURES on the top page are working.  They scroll to the top and then stay fixed while other pictures scroll over them.

Answer (score 0):

it's a simple case of adding `position: fixed;` to a block at the top of your HTML content. Here's a very basic example:

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#top-bar{
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    position: fixed;
}
#content{
    height: 3000px;
    padding-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <div id="top-bar"></div>
  <div id="content">
    AAA<br />
    BBB<br />
    CCC<br />
    DDD<br />
    EEE<br />
    FFF<br />
    XXX<br />
    YYY<br />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It basically looks for the height of your screen with: `window.innerHeight` and adds a class when the amount scrolled is bigger than the height of your screen.

This is the same height as the #introscreen, which is set to 100vh with css. 100vh is basically the same as 100% ([More on VH here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length)).

So the 'navbar' is always just below the users' screen, and once you scroll this exact amount, it adds the class 'fixed' which fixes the navbar to the screen. If you scroll back the class gets removed again.