# jquery 2.2: navbar fixed on scroll not working with vh-unit

Tags: jquery

I only found this on my topic but it doesn't help me out here: [How to implement scroll to fixed effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31668922/how-to-implement-scroll-to-fixed-effect/31680063#31680063)

I'm trying to implement a navbar, which sticks to the top when the user scrolled over the header-section as can be seen here:
https://teamtreehouse.com/community/forum-tip-create-a-sticky-navigation-with-css-and-jquery-2

However, since I'm using vh and vw units in this project, i got problems getting the jQuery to work. It's working fine, if I use px like

```
...
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 400 )
...
```

but with

```
...
if ($(this).scrollTop() > $("#slider_part").height
...
```

it's not working.

See my Code below. And Thanks in Advance for your Answers!

```
My HTML:

<header id="slider_part">
  <div>...</div>
</header>
<div id="main-nav" class="navbar">
 <nav>...</nav>
</div>

CSS:

#slider_part {
   height: 85vh;
   width: 100%;
   overflow:hidden;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   z-index: -100;
   }

#main-nav {
   position: relative;
   background: #DB2F27;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
   box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
   z-index: 150;
   border: none !important;
   }

.navbar {
  height: 15vh;
  width: 100vw;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  }

.main-nav-scrolled {
  width: 100vw;
  position: fixed !important;
  top: 0;
  }

jQuery:

var mn = $(".navbar");

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > $("#slider_part").height ) {
        mn.addClass("main-nav-scrolled");
    }
    else {
        mn.removeClass("main-nav-scrolled");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check errors in console, as you have missed `()` for the `.height()` method:

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() > $("#slider_part").height() ) {
```

Another suggestion to use `.toggleClass()` method:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    mn.toggleClass('main-nav-scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > $("#slider_part").height());
});
```

In the above example the class will be added when the condition is true and removed when false.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Somehow I was blind!